# Is there no stack segment? Is it simply a concept?

Tags: c, assembly, objdump

I have been doing some tests and realized that it is wrong to say that the stack segment exists, because when I analyze a binary, I realized that any data type, which is neither in the register nor in static, global or constant, is in the text segment. Do you agree with me about this? I'm really in doubt, I always thought it was right to call heap and stack memory segments.I know the concept exists, but not a segment

Compile: gcc example.c -c

Ex: objdump -s example.o

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

     char s[] = "string";
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The heap and stack do not exist until run-time (if ever).

Comment: I think this maybe platform-specific, so you should specify what platform you're on.

Comment: @Thomas I'm on debian, x86_64 architecture

Comment: You need to allocate space for the stack in advance though. So there will be a stack segment in the binary, but obviously no variables will be put there at link-time.

Comment: @Lundin: x86-64 Linux ELF binaries *don't* have a stack segment in the ELF Program Headers (`readelf -l a.out`). Every process gets a stack implicitly for its main thread (with argc,argv above RSP), and the kernel chooses the initial size, with the max growth limited by `ulimit -s`, not set by anything in the binary.  (The binary can [ask for the stack to be mapped executable](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/GNU_stack_quickstart#Finding_ELFs_that_ask_for_an_executable_stack), though, with a `GNU_STACK` segment in the program headers.  e.g. for GCC pointer-to-nested-function trampolines.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah well it's obviously wildly system-specific. I mostly deal with ELF and similar for microcontrollers, and then you need to set aside memory for the stack manually.

Comment: @Lundin: Interesting.  Either way it's always uninitialized memory, as you say.  (except for argc,argv[],env[] above the stack pointer on process entry, depending on the ABI).  \@Yuri: It makes no sense to have initialized data on the stack before functions that use it are called; the linker wouldn't know where to put it to line up with the exact value of the stack pointer, among other problems.

Comment: I'm still starting in the C language and assembly, so I do not understand much. Could you pass some blog or book reference that explains well about the build process and what does Linkitor do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably refer to this:

> Contents of section .text:
>
> 0000 554889e5 c745f073 74726966 c745f46e  UH...E.strif.E.n
>
> 0010 67c645f6 00b80000 00005dc3           g.E.......].

You can see the string "string" in the text section, because this statement

```
char s[] = "string";
```

leads to code, which copies the string to the stack. `objdump -d` shows

Disassembly of section .text:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   c7 45 f0 73 74 72 69    movl   $0x69727473,-0x10(%rbp)
   b:   66 c7 45 f4 6e 67       movw   $0x676e,-0xc(%rbp)
...
```

The last two instructions move "string" on the stack, since it operates with immediate values you can see the string in the hexdump. Nevertheless, it lives on the stack at runtime.

Comment: So, it is correct to say that before executing the string is in the text section, so dps go to the segment of the stack?

Comment: Not really, since the string itself indeed isn't on the stack, just the opcodes to _create_ it on the stack. You see for example, that the string isn't available as a single piece. The compiler could for example create a memset-like code for an initialization like `char a[] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";`, then the string would not be available at all prior to runtime

Comment: Thanks for the answers, just one more question. Because when you use the -d argument, do not show the other sections, only the text? The objdump does not display the .rodata section, which was previously displayed when using the -s flag.

Comment: `-d` is "disassembly" and it is usually only sensible to disassemble the `.text` section. However, you can insist to disassemble all sections with the flag `-D` instead of `-d`

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that in the section .rodata does not show the opcodes, but the bytes in hexadecimal of the string, already in main, it shows the opcodes, because it will be?